# find the maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths in a graph with a constraint

Tags: algorithm, graph, theory, np-complete

Given a undirected graph G=(V,E), each edge is associated with a non-negative value.

How to find the maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths from s to t on the graph G, with a constraint that the sum of paths length is not greater than a predefined value T.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the context of this problem?

Comment: what's your real meaning of *maximum number of vertex-disjoint paths*? Is it the path with the greatest length, or with the most node, or the total number of different paths?

Comment: @Skyler, I think he mean maximum number of vertex-independent paths. – Ido.Co 5 mins ago

Answer (score 5):

You can start with transforming a vertex-disjoint paths problem to edge-disjoint paths problem. See [this answer to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916273/1009831) for details.

Now you can solve [Minimum-cost flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) on this graph to find any number of disjoint paths having minimal sum of path lengths. Do do this, assign flow capacity for each edge equal to 1, then search for a minimum-cost flow between s and t with flow equal to the needed number of paths.

To find the maximum number of paths, apply minimum-cost flow procedure on each step of binary search, starting from some initial number of paths, which may be determined by one of the following procedures:

1. If you expect the maximum number of paths to be large, solve [Maximum flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) for this graph.
2. If you expect the maximum number of paths to be small, use one-sided binary search (also with minimum-cost flow procedure on each step).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only interested in the **number** of vertex-disjoint paths you can use [Menger's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem) (for proof look [here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/agt3.pdf)) that states as follows:

Let G be a finite undirected graph and x and y two nonadjacent vertices. Then the theorem states that the size of the minimum vertex cut for x and y (the minimum number of vertices whose removal disconnects x and y) is equal to the maximum number of pairwise vertex-independent paths from x to y.

But this doesn't satisfy the constraint that the sum of paths length is not greater than a predefined value T.

For that you'll have to use a version of of Menger's theorem for paths of bounded length
that is presented [here](http://www.math.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/mengerian.pdf): http://www.math.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/mengerian.pdf